# Forcing a particular MPI compiler with CMake

Tags: cmake

I want to set a particular MPI compiler (`mpiifort`) with CMake. Well, not the compiler, but get the libraries and include directories from it. But there is also `mpif90` in the path, which uses `gfortran` under the hood, and has a different set of include dirs and libraries. It seems the `FindMPI` module in CMake insists on locating `mpif90` first and therefore sets the wrong paths.

I've tried setting `MPI_Fortran_COMPILER=mpiifort` in the command line, or setting `FC=mpiifort`, but none works. So far the only workaround I've found is creating a symlink `mpif90 -> mpiifort` in the current directory and adding `_MPI_PREFIX_PATH=.`. Any other ideas?

EDIT: I had tried the *environment variable* `MPI_Fortran_COMPILER`, but I had to set the *CMake variable* instead. So this worked:

```
FC=ifort CC=icc cmake -D MPI_Fortran_COMPILER=mpiifort ...
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the source [here](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindMPI.cmake#L51), if setting MPI_Fortran_COMPILER does not work, then you could simply set MPI_Fortran_LIBRARIES and MPI_Fortran_INCLUDE_PATH.